Non-www not redirecting to www HTTPS Nginx
I am pretty new to nginx and have tried fixing the issue with a number of different solutions on this site and elsewhere but still can not resolve the non-www to www. The odd thing is that another server block that I have is doing it without issue. I used letsencrypt for the SSL cert. My config file is:
server {
     location / {
         root /var/www/example.com;
         try_files $uri /index.html;
     }
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     listen [::]:443 ssl;
     listen 443 ssl;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
     include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
     ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
 server_name example.com www.example.com;

 if ($host = example.com) {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }

 if ($host = www.example.com) {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }

 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;

 return 404;
}

I have tried substituting the https://$host$request_uri; where $host = example.com for https://www.example.com$request_uri; and that doesn't work either. In the network tab I am getting a status of '(failed) net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED', but my config is the same as another server block and that one is resolving correctly with both www and non-www to https.

(failed) net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED means that there is no DNS entry for www.example.com. Check your DNS provider to confirm that you have either an A record or a CNAME record for www.

Yes, this is correct. It was hard to troubleshoot because this particular domain name is managed by our MSP and is utilized for a large number of services. They were able to add the record to have it resolve correctly. It wasn't an issue with the nginx config. Thanks!

@JohnK As this is the correct answer, do please click the check mark that you see just to the left here. That will change the status of the question to "answered", and will help other people with the same problem see that there is an answer for it.

I tried, it says I don't have enough reputation points. I just started this account.

Could try filling in some profile detail, I think that gets you some reputation points.
